# SQL: How to get COUNT when using EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 'COUNT=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), COUNT(s.company)) AS sites 
FROM   site s 
WHERE  s.sitetype = 'om' 
       AND s.status = 1 
EXCEPT 
SELECT DISTINCT sg.company 
FROM   snmpmibdevice AS sdevice 
       JOIN site sg 
         ON sg.guid = sdevice.siteguid 
       JOIN snmpmibdata sdata 
         ON sdata.snmpmibdeviceguid = sdevice.snmpmibdeviceguid 
WHERE  sdata.sampletimestamp > Dateadd (mi, -15, Getutcdate()) 
       AND sg.sitetype = 'OM'
```

Basically I am attempting to return a count of company names from this. If I remove the count and just select "S.Company" I will get 2 values (I would like "COUNT=2"), but with the count it comes up as 34 records (COUNT=34).

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm). Use it. Love it.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this context, but how many rows do you expect to count?: **VARCHAR(64)**?  if you had the widest 8 byte bigint value `CONVERT(varchar(20), COUNT(s.company))` would be enough.

Comment: `...EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT...` -- you don't need the `DISTINCT` keyword because `EXCEPT` implies `EXCEPT DISTINCT` by default (bizarrely, SQL Server does not support the explicit `EXCEPT DISTINCT` and generates an "Incorrect syntax" error, whereas `EXCEPT ALL` generates a more meaningful error, "The 'ALL' version of the EXCEPT operator is not supported"). In fact, you can't override `EXCEPT DISTINCT` even if you wanted to i.e. `... EXCEPT SELECT ALL ...` would still give you `DISTINCT` results ...which is a good thing :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: Actually, all three set operators (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`) generate a syntax error in SQL Server when combined with the `DISTINCT` keyword. I agree, it's weird, because in all other places where `DISTINCT` is accepted, `ALL` is an option (albeit default) too. So, if `ALL` is accepted with these three, why not allow `DISTINCT`...

Answer (score 12):

wrap the whole thing in a "select count(*) from ()"

```
SELECT 'COUNT=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), COUNT(company)) AS sites 
FROM (

    SELECT s.company
    FROM   site s 
    WHERE  s.sitetype = 'om' 
           AND s.status = 1 
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT DISTINCT sg.company 
    FROM   snmpmibdevice AS sdevice 
           JOIN site sg 
             ON sg.guid = sdevice.siteguid 
           JOIN snmpmibdata sdata 
             ON sdata.snmpmibdeviceguid = sdevice.snmpmibdeviceguid 
    WHERE  sdata.sampletimestamp > Dateadd (mi, -15, Getutcdate()) 
           AND sg.sitetype = 'OM' 
) a
```